# Change src path backgroundImage from url to folder CSS ReactJS

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the ImageBackground from a Materail-UI Button Image component. The problem is that the CSS config requires a backgroundImage but they search throught URL browser not from my filesystem folders.

Image help links:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzFsm.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUzXK.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNM8g.jpg

```
          <span
            className={classes.imageSrc}
            style={{
              backgroundImage: "url('./juego.png')",
            }}
          />
```

The expected result is that span search from the src image throught the filesystem folder local explorer and not throught url!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this, in ES5

```
 <span
      className={classes.imageSrc}
      style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(require("path to your image file"))`,
      }}
 />
```

in ES6,

`import image from './image.jpg'     //path to file`

```
style={{backgroundImage : `url(${image})`}}
```

Comment: Really thanks! Was the require ('path image file'). Sorry for the noob question!